# java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.version" mockMVC

Tags: spring, junit, mockito, mockmvc

I written test mockMVC method get

i have this following bug

what is bad in my code? what i can fixed it?

Comment: Post the return Json after service call. Is it a flat structure like {"version":"2.0"} and are all json fields present.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your controller returns an empty response according to the line

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: json can not be null or empty
```

in your stacktrace. Try to debug the controller code and find out what it returns and why.

Comment: @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
@ApiOperation(value = "Retrieve account.")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<AccountDTO> getAccount(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return accountService.retreiveById(id).map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}

Comment: this is method get of controller